# logback : level OFF isn't working in logback

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I'm working on a project where I use slf4j with logback for logging. The thing is the level of logs are dynamic and are chosen by the user. So, the user can also stop the logging so he could gain on space (we log many things and it can be quickly very costly if there's a big traffic).

So to do that, I save some variables in a properties file and I reload it every time it's changed. But I didn't succeded to make it work with the level off (for disabling logs) as [the doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html) says.

Here's my logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="false"> 
<!-- We don't need the logback.xml to be checked every time, we will trigger in java
the reload if we need it -->

    <property file="/opt/program/log.properties"/>

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <!-- To enable JMX Management -->
    <jmxConfigurator/>

    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${PATTERN_LOGS}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

     <appender name="generalFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
         <file>${LOG_GENERAL_PATH}.log</file>
         <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_GENERAL_FILENAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
          </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${PATTERN_LOGS}</pattern>
        </encoder>
      </appender>

      <appender name="httpFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
         <file>${LOG_HTTP_PATH}.log</file>
         <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HTTP_FILENAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
          </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${PATTERN_LOGS}</pattern>
        </encoder>
      </appender>

       <appender name="errorFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
         <file>${LOG_ERROR_PATH}.log</file>
         <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ERROR_FILENAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
          </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${PATTERN_LOGS}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
      </appender>

     <logger name="http" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="httpFile"/>
        <appender-ref ref="generalFile"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="${LEVEL_ROOT}">
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        <appender-ref ref="generalFile"/>
        <appender-ref ref="errorFile"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And this is what I got from the console when I activate status message:

```
00:06:45,861 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
00:06:45,861 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
00:06:45,862 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/root/Documents/project/projet%20OSM/Tomcat%20Installation/wtpwebapps/SekaiServer/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
00:06:45,944 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerContextListenerAction - Adding LoggerContextListener of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator] to the object stack
00:06:45,961 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@3b0933e7 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
00:06:45,962 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerContextListenerAction - Starting LoggerContextListener
00:06:45,962 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.JMXConfiguratorAction - begin
00:06:45,968 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
00:06:45,975 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [console]
00:06:45,993 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
00:06:46,091 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
00:06:46,100 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [generalFile]
00:06:46,143 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
00:06:46,148 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern /opt/program/log/general.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
00:06:46,155 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/opt/program/log/general.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
00:06:46,155 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
00:06:46,156 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Sat Mar 26 00:03:15 CET 2016
00:06:46,159 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
00:06:46,165 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[generalFile] - Active log file name: /opt/program//log/general.log
00:06:46,165 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[generalFile] - File property is set to [/opt/program//log/general.log]
00:06:46,167 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
00:06:46,168 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [httpFile]
00:06:46,170 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
00:06:46,170 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern /opt/program/log/http.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
00:06:46,171 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/opt/program/log/http.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
00:06:46,171 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
00:06:46,172 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Sat Mar 26 00:03:15 CET 2016
00:06:46,172 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
00:06:46,174 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[httpFile] - Active log file name: /opt/program//log/http.log
00:06:46,174 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[httpFile] - File property is set to [/opt/program//log/http.log]
00:06:46,174 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
00:06:46,175 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [errorFile]
00:06:46,177 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
00:06:46,177 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern /opt/program/log/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
00:06:46,178 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/opt/program/log/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
00:06:46,178 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
00:06:46,178 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Thu Mar 24 19:50:38 CET 2016
00:06:46,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
00:06:46,190 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[errorFile] - Active log file name: /opt/program//log/error.log
00:06:46,190 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[errorFile] - File property is set to [/opt/program//log/error.log]
00:06:46,192 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [http] to DEBUG
00:06:46,192 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@3b0933e7 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[http] onto the JUL framework
00:06:46,192 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [http] to false
00:06:46,192 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [httpFile] to Logger[http]
00:06:46,194 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [generalFile] to Logger[http]
00:06:46,194 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [console] to Logger[http]
00:06:46,194 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to OFF
00:06:46,194 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@3b0933e7 - Propagating OFF level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
00:06:46,194 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [console] to Logger[ROOT]
00:06:46,194 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [generalFile] to Logger[ROOT]
00:06:46,194 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [errorFile] to Logger[ROOT]
00:06:46,195 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
00:06:46,195 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@78865c1d - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Comment: What do the status messages say? See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#statusListener details.

Comment: It's a plaisure for me to have your assistance in my questions. I had added the logs in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the logback status messages you provided, the root logger is set to level OFF as expected. However, the logger named "http" is set to DEBUG which I suspect is the source of the problem.

In any case, referencing the same appender from different loggers is a bad idea. Moreover, the config file does it twice, with appenders named 'generalFile' and 'errorFile'. **Again, referencing the same appender from different loggers is a bad idea and is not supported.**

Comment: Thank you it's working. Now I got a problem because when I remove the appender `generalFIle` and `console` from logger http, I lose  `http` logs in "generalFile" and in "console".

Comment: In logger named http, set additivity to true, or just remove the additivity attribute and it will default to true.