# Suppress spring boot printing error to stderr

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, logging

I have a try/catch/finally block in the entry point to my service (the class that polls an item from SQS).
I want to catch every exception thrown from within my service and throw it out, so SQS can re-drive it.
However, this also causes the spring boot container to print the stack trace to the console, which in turn logs it into my log aggregator.
I already have an infra for meaningful logging, which adds important metadata to every log message using MDC, and hence I'd like to use it when logging the exception.

This is my code:

```
@SqsListener(value = "${src.queue.name}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NO_REDRIVE)
public void consume(String msgJson) {
    String awsKeyJson = JsonUtils.fromJson(msgJson).get("Message").asText();
    String awsKey = JsonUtils.fromJson(awsKeyJson, AwsKey.class).getKey();
    ScanResponseContainer src = s3.getResourceAsObject(SRC_BUCKET_NAME, awsKey, ScanResponseContainer.class);
    mdcService.initializeMDC(src, awsKey);
    logger.info("Received Scan Response Container from SQS");

    try {
        ScannedMerchant sm = scanResponseContainerService.handleScanResponseContainer(src);
        producer.produce(sm);
        logger.info("Successfully processed Scan Response Container");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error thrown when processing Scan Response Container", e);
    } finally {
        mdcService.clearMDC();
        eventCollector.clear();
    }
}
```

My problem is - I can add to the catch block:

```
logger.error(e);
```

And it would log the error with a meaningful log message.
However, it would still log the "unmeaningful" message, because spring would still print it to the console, and then I'll get duplicate messages in my log aggregator.
Is there some kind of interceptor I can use that will still throw the exception but suppress printing the stack trace to stderr?

Comment: Please share error stacktrace for clarity. Which logging framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the log level for the `spring boot` packages. For properties file can you set it to OFF or FATAL.

```
logging.level.org.springframework=OFF
```

If you have `xml` for logger configuration

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</logger>
```

Logback update: [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging.logback) 
Logback [Level](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/class-use/Level.html)

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209809/logback-level-off-isnt-working-in-logback) : Logback level off issue.

Comment: Wouldn't that do the opposite of what I want by logging everything (trace and above)?

Comment: My bad, log level fatal or off would suffice. Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm using logback, and apparently, there is no FATAL severity in there (ERROR is the highest). Any other workaround?

Comment: Logback has a level `OFF`. You can refer this link. https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Comment: this link might be helpful. https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/